# How does the QApplication in PyQt4 know what events are being cued?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm working through Summerfield's Python and GUI with PyQt book and I have come across something I don't understand.

At the end of each example file we have:

```
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I've read that every Qt GUI requires an application... I can accept this as true, but I don't fully understand what the QApplication DOES.

Also, how does the QApplication even know what "form" is? It isn't given an argument or pointer toward it anywhere. I'm confused about why this works.

Comment: Python does have a reflection library, so it could find form on its own

Comment: The Qt docs have detailed descriptions of [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#details) and the [Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html).